# Calculus: Find equation that represents the set of all points that are equidistant from given three points (0,0,0) (2,4,3)(10,8,9)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, analytic-geometry

So it is essential circumcenter problem in 3D that involves multivariable calculus. If you could at least help with the ideas or steps of tackling this problem that would be great

PS: I made up the points, if somehow they do not work feel free to use other three points in the space.

Thanks!

Comment: Is this not just the line through the 2D circumcenter, perpendicular to the plane defined by the three points?

Comment: I don't think this is differential geometry, or (miltivariate or not) calculus.

Answer (score 2):

Procedure. Given points $P,Q,R$, take two of the points, say $P,Q$, and construct (describe, find an equation) of the plane that passes through their midpoint, and is perpendicular to the line segment connecting them. Take another pair of points, say $P,R$ and repeat the procedure. Intersect the two planes obtained in the previous steps. Obtain a line, which is the set of all points equidistant from $P,Q,R$.

Answer (score 0):

You need to solve
$$
x^2+y^2+z^2=(x-2)^2+(y-4)^2+(z-3)^2=(x-10)^2+(y-8)^2+(z-9)^2,
$$
each equation is the distance (squared) from $(x,y,z)$ to your three points.